# How to get data from a specific API website using Python

Tags: python, api

So I'm trying to randomly generate an insult from this [API](https://insult.mattbas.org/api/). I'm getting a response 200 from the API but I can't seem to extract data

I'm using this code:

```
def get_insult():
  res = requests.get('https://insult.mattbas.org/api/insult.txt')
  print(res)
  data_json = json.loads(res.json())
  print(data_json)
  

get_insult()
```

Comment: Okay, so where the code says `print(data_json)`, **what happens**? What exactly do you mean by "can't seem to extract data"? What steps did you take to try to extract the data, and what happened when you tried those steps? Do you understand **what** the `data_json` result is (i.e., its type, not just what it looks like when `print`ed)? Did you try to read the documentation for the API, in order to understand how the JSON is structured?

Comment: Where the code says `res.json()`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? What sort of result do you expect to get back: the raw text of a JSON document, or the parsed JSON data structure? Why? (did you try to read the documentation, in order to find out which?) Therefore, does it make sense to try to use `json.loads` on the result?

Comment: Did you try to use the API by visiting the URL yourself in a web browser? When you do this, **do you see JSON data**? Therefore, does it make sense to try to process a JSON result? (Again: did you **read the documentation** for the API?)

Comment: On the API website, it has three formats and I was trying to use both Text and JSON format. And I was kind of lost in trying to get result since I thought only JSON format can be passed but turns out text format can also be used which actually solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You don't need to use `json.loads()` as the response is not `json`.

```
 def get_insult():
      res = requests.get('https://insult.mattbas.org/api/insult.txt')
      data_json = res.text
      print(data_json)
      
 get_insult()
```

Comment: try this now, I have updated the code. response is not `JSON` so we don't need to use `JSON`

Comment: on the second thought, It worked. Thank you so much. But quick question, if I change the format into json like 

res = requests.get('https://insult.mattbas.org/api/insult.json')

should I use json.loads()

Comment: yes in that case you can use `json.loads(res.text)`